# Automating Python Script and saving outputted table into sql server database

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a large chunk of python code that outputs a final dataframe. I would like to:

1. Have this script run in VSCode every morning
2. Save this final table in my sql server database.

One thing to note is that the python code begins by accessing sql server to import two datasets that the rest of the code then alters into a final dataset. When accessing the sql server database in the beginning, it asks for my credentials. So my third question is:

3. Is there a way, when automating the python script that I can have it automatically input my credentials or will I have to manually import this everytime?

I am mostly looking for resources on this and if anyone has any helpful tips/links I would be appreciative! I have tried looking for links but can't seem to find much.

Answer (score 0):

1. That seems unnecessary, just use a cron job or a scheduled task and run the script directly.
2. Sure, look into `sqlite3` or `SQLAlchemy` or browse the pip repository.
3. You could just include them in your code or in a separate file.